# Implement error message for trait specialization of class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, sfinae, specialization

How to implement an error message when the library user uses the wrong type for a template argument of a template class?

test.cpp (adapt from [here](http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/class-template-sfinae.html))

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class foo; // Sorry, foo<T> for non-integral type T has not been implemented.

template <typename T>
class foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{ };

int main()
{
    foo<float> x;
}
```

The code does not compile, as expected. But I can't make the compiler show an error only when the user used the wrong type.

Error message of `g++ test.cpp`

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:13: error: aggregate ‘foo<float> x’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  foo<float> x;
```

Problem: It doesn't print the error message that I want (`Sorry, foo<T> for non-integral type T has not been implemented.`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) will do the trick:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class foo
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Sorry, foo<T> for non-integral type T has not been implemented");
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b63a8a072e52941)

You need the `sizeof(T) == 0` because the `static_assert` is always evaluated, and needs to depend on `T` otherwise it will always trigger, even for valid `T`.